# JavaFX MapProperty issue with adding multiple listeners

Tags: javafx

When I add a second listener to the Java MapProperty neither one seems to respond.

```
MapProperty<String, String> mp =
        new SimpleMapProperty<String, String>(
                FXCollections.observableHashMap());

mp.addListener((obv1, ov1, nv1) -> {
    System.out.format("1: mp: %s%n", nv1);
});
mp.put("key1", "object1");

mp.addListener((obv2, ov2, nv2) -> {
    System.out.format("2: mp: %s%n", nv2);
});
mp.put("key2", "object2");
```

After the second addListener, it stops printing. The output is:

```
1: mp: {key1=object1}
```

When I comment out adding the second mp.addListener, it prints both additions.

```
1: mp: {key1=object1}
1: mp: {key2=object2, key1=object1}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I see the same behavior. That looks like a bug to me.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to submit a bug, but for Java FX it doesn't seem easy.

Comment: To submit a bug, just register at https://javafx-jira.kenai.com and you can submit it.

Comment: I was there before, but you can't see much of anything on the site until you create an account and log in, which I did. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you add an empty MapChangeListener that doesn't do anything (or one that does do something) it seems to resolve the issue.

```
mp.addListener(new MapChangeListener<String, String>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(Change<? extends String, ? extends String> map) {}
});
```

Now the output is as expected.

```
1: mp: {key1=object1}
1: mp: {key2=object2, key1=object1}
2: mp: {key2=object2, key1=object1}
```

Seems to support that it's a bug.

Comment: I advise you to file a bug report at: https://javafx-jira.kenai.com and edit your answer to include a link to the bug report.

Comment: Created an account on the JIRA site and created bug ID RT-39857 (https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-39857).

Also discovered that the problem is caused by calling the put method before adding the second addListener. Moving the first put to after the second addListener produces the desired output.